# Avoiding duplicate service calls in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, soa

I have got the below service classes:

**AccountService class:**

```
public class AccountService {
    public createAccount(argumentsList1);
    public closeAccount(argumentsList2);
    //many other methods
}
```

**ServiceHandler class:**

```
public class ServiceHandler {//ServiceHandler is singleton

    SavingsAccountService savingsAccountService;//SavingsAccountService implements AccountService

    LoanAccountService loanAccountService;//LoanAccountService implements AccountService

    public AccountService getService(boolean isSavings) {
        if(isSavings) {
            return savingsAccountService;
        } else {
            return loanAccountService;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have got many different types of services like `ABCService`, `XYZService`, etc.. which invoke `ServiceHandler` first to get the runtime object of AccountService and then invoke the respective method as shown in the below example:

**ABCService class:**

```
public class ABCService {
    public void process1(boolean isSavingsAccount, a, b, c, arguments..) {
        AccountService accountService = ServiceHandler.getService(isSavingsAccount);
        accountService.createAccount(argumentsList1);
    }
}
```

**XYZService class:**

```
public class XYZService {
    public void process2(boolean isSavingsAccount, d, e, f, argumemts...) {
        AccountService accountService = ServiceHandler.getService(isSavingsAccount);
        accountService.closeAccount(argumentsList2);
    }
}
```

There are many other services like `PQRService` (similar to `ABCService`, `XYZService`), etc..
Here, I did not like duplicating the call to the `ServiceHandler.getService(isSavingsAccount)` in all other services (like `ABCService`, etc..) first to get the handle and then further invoking the required methods `createAccount()`, `closeAccount()`, etc.. How can I expose the methods of `AccountService` through `ServiceHandler` itself (so that I can call `createAccount()` with a single line of code)?
Note that `ServiceHandler` is a singleton class and should be threadsafe.

Is there any specific design pattern that I can use to eliminate the above duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the `Dependency Injection` principle

- Make all your services depend on supertype `AccountService`
- Compute `getService(isSavings)` only once to determine the required concrete `AccountService` eithier `SavingsAccountService` or `LoanAccountService` at runtime
- Inject this into your services

Sample code for more clarification

ABCService class:

```
public class ABCService {
    // inject the service using constructor or setter method
    private AccountService accountService;

    public void process1(a, b, c, arguments..) {
        accountService.createAccount(argumentsList1);
    }
}
```

XYZService class:

```
public class XYZService {
    // inject the service using constructor or setter method
    private AccountService accountService;

    public void process1(d, e, f, argumemts...) {
        accountService.closeAccount(argumentsList1);
    }
}
```

Hint:
If you need the client to pass `isSavings` boolean parameter each time at runtime, so your solution fit the requirrment
Mainly you applied `Factory method Design pattern`, just rename `ServiceHandler` class to `AccountServiceFactory` for more readability

Comment: I can't inject the `AccountService` using the constructor or setter method as `isSavings` will be provided at runtime.